# Threading Tkinter Button Executes Code Immediately

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a tkinter GUI, and am interested in adding a threading component to prevent my program from freezing. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import threading
root = Tk()
root.title('Calculation Program')
root.geometry('700x525')
def param_log_export():
    to_discover = disc_mode_choice.get()

def RunCalculation():
    os.system('python command_center.py')

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func
run_click_frame= Canvas(root, width= 450, height= 525)
save_button = Button(run_click_frame, width=450,height=1,text='Run Analysis!',fg='white',relief='flat',borderwidth=5, 
                    bg='#2F4FAA',font=(Font_tuple,15),command = threading.Thread(target=combine_funcs(param_log_export,RunCalculation)).start())
save_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Essentially when the button is clicked, another script is called, and that script calls all of the smaller scripts for a certain calculation:

```
from target_list_create import mh_table
from ion_list_format import ion_mod_full
from theo_list_generation import theo_list_record
from precursor_fragment_matching import precursor_matches
```

Previously, I was just using `command=combine_functs(param_log_export,RunCalculation)`, which worked fine, other than beginning to freeze as the size of my calculations grows. So, now I am trying the threading approach using the above code, but before I even have the opportunity to click the button which would command the threaded script, the program is running as though the button was clicked immediately. The console returns: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fdr_algorithm_report' referenced before assignment`, which indicates that there is a leak and the program triggers the `combine_functs` function as soon as the GUI is executed.

If anyone could help me understand what the issue is, so that when I click the button it executes the command without freezing the program, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: You don't need the brackets after `start`

Comment: maybe try putting the call in a lambda function? sometimes, especially in tkinter, in order for the function to not be called when a `tk` object (in this case, a `tk.Button`) is initialized, it needs to be in a lambda, which will be executed on the click.

Comment: `command = threading.Thread(target=combine_funcs(param_log_export,RunCalculation)).start()` will _immediately_ call `threading.Thread(target=combine_funcs(param_log_export,RunCalculation)).start()`, and pass the result of that method to the `command` attribute.

Comment: My recommendation is to create a separate function for the callback of your button.  Using `lambda` makes the code hard to read and hard to debug, and arguably should only be used when there is no better alternative.